# Youtrack time report coworker free hours per day

Tags: youtrack

Does anybody knows how can I create a youtrack report which show how many free hours left for a user per days if a day is 8 work hours?

Answer (score 1):

Partially this can be addressed by Time report, Per-user mode. You can create daily reports and check Spent time VS Estimation. Though it's not the best approach, but at least it's available at the moment.
We have this task for managing resources https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-29980 , please upvote.

Comment: I've downvoted for the instructional value: generally it is the case that experienced users know a fair set of the unwritten writing rules here, and if you roll them back, you are claiming that you know them better. I am all ears if you believe that answers are for the purposes of garnering votes on an external website, but that doesn't feel in keeping with the spirit of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Looks like you didn't receive my message I left when rolling back your change. Actually I added the comment twice, because wasn't sure it was added correctly. BTW, I still don't see my comment. How did you add this one to your revision: `The link is helpful, but answers are not for the purposes of getting external votes` ? 
Collecting votes indeed is not a goal.The intention is to show that it's known feature request and if you want to receive updates on this request and participate in the process, you can vote or add yourself to watchers. What's wrong here? Why cannot users watch for updates?

Comment: Well, now I can say, I feel a bit disappointed because of your downvoting.